# Setting the same condition for multiple breakpoints in a single step.(Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

I want to set a single condition for multiple breakpoints. Is there any way to do this in eclipse in a single step rather than editing each breakpoint and setting the condition?

Comment: Which way do you use to do this? Via breakpoint properties dialogs? In the _Breakpoints_ view you can do this without having to open the breakpoint properties dialog for each breakpoint.

Comment: @howlger I did not see an option to set a common condition to all breakpoints in the Breakpoints view.

Comment: No one claimed that. In the _Breakpoints_ view, you can easily copy strings from one breakpoint to another, so editing multiple breakpoints at once would save just a few mouse clicks. However, if you think this would be a useful feature, this should not be a Stack Overflow question, but a feature request (if you select multiple breakpoints, you will see that multiple breakpoints cannot be edited at once) reported to Eclipse along with a code contribution. Eclipse is open source and you are a Java developer, right?